# c# How to make that selected item from listbox will be shown in label?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

So I have a question, where to put that code in Windows Forms that it would be refreshed every time I select other item in listbox?
I tried to put in listBox1, but it crash my whole program, I tried to put it in `public Form2()`  but it show just first selected item in label4, and do not refresh after I select other item in listBox1. Any solutions?

```
    var selected = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    label4.Text = selected;
```

full code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;`

namespace VocaFlash_Japanese
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public List<string> words = new List<string>();
        public string Wor;
        public int State = 0;


        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            loadfile();
            listBox1.DataSource = words;
            //var selected = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
          //  label4.Text = selected;

            hidetext();

        }
        private void hidetext()
        {
            textBox1.Hide();
            textBox2.Hide();
            textBox3.Hide();
            label1.Hide();
            label2.Hide();
            label3.Hide();
        }
        private void showtext()
        {
            textBox1.Show();
            textBox2.Show();
            textBox3.Show();
            label1.Show();
            label2.Show();
            label3.Show();
        }
        public void Save()
        {
            const string sPath = "Data.txt";
            System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sPath);
            foreach (string item in words)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(item);
            }

            sw.Close();
        }
        private void UpdateListBox(List<string> words)
        {
            //string contents = null;
            List<string> itemAll = new List<string>();
            foreach (string str in words)
            {
                itemAll.Add(str);
            }
        }
        /*public void Save(List<string> words)
        {
            StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string s in words)
            {
                contents.AppendLine(s);
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"Data.txt", contents.ToString());
        }*/
        private void loadfile()
        {
            string line;
            var file = new System.IO.StreamReader("Data.txt");
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                words.Add(line);
            }
        }
       /* private void Remove()
        {
            string contents = null;
            List<string> itemAll = new List<string>();
            foreach (string str in words)
            {
                itemAll.Add(str);
            }
            foreach (string lstitem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
            {
                itemAll.Remove(lstitem);
                //File.AppendAllText(strFile + "Currently In.txt", strName + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            foreach (string s in itemAll)
            { contents += s + Environment.NewLine; }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"Data.txt", contents);

        }*/
        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           var selected = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            label4.Text = selected;
        }


        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Meniu men = new Meniu();
            men.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            State += 1;
            switch (State)
            {
                case 1:
                    showtext();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    words.Add(textBox1.Text);

                    listBox1.DataSource = null;
                    listBox1.DataSource = words;

                    Save();

                    State = 0;
                    textBox1.Text = "";

                    hidetext();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           /* // The Remove button was clicked.
            int selectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;

            try
            {
                // Remove the item in the List.
                words.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            listBox1.DataSource = null;
            listBox1.DataSource = words;
            Remove();*/
            // The Remove button was clicked.
            int selectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;

            try
            {
                // Remove the item in the List.
                words.RemoveAt(selectedIndex); //Remove item from words
                UpdateListBox(words);//Update contents on GUI
                Save(); //Save on IO
                listBox1.DataSource = null;
                listBox1.DataSource = words;

            }
            catch
            {
            }


        }

        private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hook a change event to the list, then set the text in the event handler. [Example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @DobisLT can you explain which form has the ListBox control in the future it would really help if you would show all relevant code because one cannot determine which form you are trying to update.. and if it crashes you whole program then you need to understand how to instantiate a form object meaning how to create an instance of `Form2` for example please edit the question and paste in all relevant code so others won't have to guess

Comment: just curious what the data in the file looks like I would replace the while loop with a single line of code to read all the text in the file at once with `1` line of code.. 
`words = File.ReadAllLines("Data.txt").ToList();`

Comment: in your method that hides or shows `private void hidetext()` I would create a method that utilizes the `Controls` class and do a `foreach(Control ctrl in Controls) then check it the type is `TextBox` then make visible true then in the next conditional check check if control is `Label` do the same for showtext method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to double click in the designer on the events tab for the ListBox1 control to have it automatically create the  `SelectedIndexChanged` 
just find that `SelectedIndexChanged` and double click it

inside the event put the following code

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var selected = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedValue);
    label4.Text = selected; 
}
```

Comment: But if I add this code, my program crashes and no longer able to add new words, and blue mark stuck

Comment: It stuck if I want to add new item

Comment: you need to show your full code that pertains to the forms and how you are trying to assign labels based on selectedindex being changed,  this code should not cause your program to crash unless you are trying to access it from the wrong form. also you stated that you're trying to add new item.. but nowhere in the code that you have posted do you indicate that you add items to a Listbox control.. we are not mind readers .. please show all relevant code also start using the debugger don't just code and go..

Comment: Super simple! But 'listBox1.SelectedValue' gives you the numeric index value. Use 'listBox1.SelectedItem' to get the actual text value from the selection.